# How to remove arrow from ColorCanvas dropdown control in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using c# wpf ColorCanvas control for using colors in my application.I want to remove dropdown arrow from ColorCanvas control.
I am using this Xaml Code for ColorCanvas
`<xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="canvas_Copy" ColorMode="ColorCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="93,323,409,0" />`

[image]

For clarity check this image.I want to remove this Arrow form ColorCanvas.

Comment: That Arrow seems like a DropDown (ComboBox) to me. You will have to find the Style/Template of the xctk:ColorPicker and then override/restyle that DropDown "Part_Editor" - to make it appear like you need. Slightly more demanding but can be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a custom `ButtonStyle`:

```
<xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="canvas_Copy" ColorMode="ColorCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="93,323,409,0" >
    <xctk:ColorPicker.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </xctk:ColorPicker.Resources>
    <xctk:ColorPicker.ButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton" xmlns:chrome="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Chromes;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
                                </Border>
                                <chrome:ButtonChrome x:Name="ToggleButtonChrome"
                                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                                    CornerRadius="0,2.75,2.75,0"
                                                    Visibility="{Binding ShowDropDownButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=xctk:ColorPicker}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                                    RenderChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=xctk:ColorPicker}}"
                                                    RenderEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=xctk:ColorPicker}}"
                                                    RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                                    RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}">
                                </chrome:ButtonChrome>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </xctk:ColorPicker.ButtonStyle>
</xctk:ColorPicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ColorCanvas control from the same namespace instead of ColorPicker.

Answer (score -1):

finds its css file (or its styling file) and change its color to match its background